# Onkeyup event for multiple input field in JavaScript or Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, spring-boot, onkeyup

I have multiple input fields and I want to apply key up JavaScript event on some of input field. Basically, I want to do some expense calculation and I want to get total expenses and set final expense amount in input field to display. So, I tried to apply keyup on multiple input field but did not work.

```
$('#tripfuel','#cardfee','#loadrepair','#shoprepair','#truckrent','#comcheck','#advance','#othercharge').on('keyup', function () {
        var fuel = document.getElementById('tripfuel').value;
        var cardfee = document.getElementById('cardfee').value;
        var onloadrepair = document.getElementById('loadrepair').value;
        var shoprepair = document.getElementById('shoprepair').value;
        var trailerrent = document.getElementById('truckrent').value;
        var comcheck = document.getElementById('comcheck').value;
        var advance = document.getElementById('advance').value;
        var miscellenous = document.getElementById('othercharge').value;
        var expense = parseFloat(amount)-parseFloat(fuel)-parseFloat(cardfee)-parseFloat(onloadrepair)-parseFloat(shoprepair)-parseFloat(trailerrent)-parseFloat(comcheck)-parseFloat(advance)-parseFloat(miscellenous);
        console.log("Total Expense : || "+expense); 
        document.getElementById('totalamount').value = parseFloat(expense).toFixed(2);
    });
```

[image: Screenshot to display fields]

Comment: jQuery Documentation https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/

Answer (score 1):

apply the class of all of your expenses input like

```
 <input type="text" class="expenses" />
```

then get the total value like this.

```
$('.expenses').on('keyup', function () {
   let totalExpense = 0;
    $(document).find("input.expenses").each(function(){
       totalExpense += parseFloat($(this).val())
   })
});
```